# redirect tralling slash to no extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

my htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

now it works like this:

```
mydomain.com/contact.php (  redirect --> )   mydomain.com/contact
mydomain.com/contact/    (  redirect --> )   404 - not found:(
mydomain.com/contact     (  redirect --> )   mydomain.com/contact
```

how redirect "mydomain.com/contact/" to: "mydomain.com/contact" ?
or maybe just let the browser to open correct page, not 404 like it is now :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: still redirecting to 404 :/

Comment: http://mydomainname.com/contact/   redirect -->   404 Problem is only with trailing slash

Comment: Is `/contact/` a directory as well?

Comment: it is a file: /contact.php same with others like /news.php etc. I just want to make sure that user will be redirect to correct page even if he will type in trailing slash at the and. Now when the visitor type: domain.com/contact/ he get 404

Comment: to low reputation of my account :/

Comment: No not asking you to upvote. Just click on tick mark on to-left of my answer to make it green.